# Laravel API Errors and Exceptions: How to Return Responses

Tags: php, laravel, api

Status Code Meaning
404 Not Found (page or other resource doesn’t exist)
401 Not authorized (not logged in)
403 Logged in but access to requested area is forbidden
400 Bad request (something wrong with URL or parameters)
422 Unprocessable Entity (validation failed)
500 General server error

Comment: hey, welcome to stackoverflow. your question is very broad, try narrowing it down, what do you want accomplished? do you want to return the error codes? do you want to return a response? etc

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want something dynamic like 200 for a successful route, 201 for a successful request, 422 for a failed validation and things like that. Add this to your controller

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

Your delete method should now look like this

```
public function destroy(Job $job)
    {
        //I'm applying model binding
        $job->delete();
        return response([], Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

Your update method should e something like this

```
public function update(Job $job)
    {
        //I'm using model binding and a resource in my case
        $job->update($this->validateRequest());
        return (new JobResource($job))
            ->response()
            ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

Your store method should be something like this

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //I've used a Resource on my Job model
        $job = Job::create($this->validateRequest());

        return (new JobResource($job))
                    ->response()
                    ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
```

This is a sample validate request

```
private function validateRequest()
    {
        return request()->validate([
            'title'=> 'required|unique:jobs',
            'comment' => 'sometimes'
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what do you want, but you can make your own custom **`JSON response()`** with custom status code using [JSON responses](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/responses#json-responses)

```
return response()->json(['error' => 'Page not found'], 404);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a response in json format:

```
return response()->json(['error' => 'Page not found'], 404);
```

If you also want to display a customized message. Just add this function from:
 `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation`. you do not need to add or require extra files.

`abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');`

on any condition you like:

```
if ( !hasRole('admin') ) {

                     abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
                 }
```

this is the function:

```
> public function abort($code, $message = '', array $headers = [])
>     {
>         if ($code == 404) {
>             throw new NotFoundHttpException($message);
>         }
> 
>         throw new HttpException($code, $message, null, $headers);
>     }
```

this is gonna show a general message, if you want to customize your page just add a folder inside `resources/view` with the name of 'errors', inside add your view with name of errors: 404, 403, etc. The number of error you call in the function, the name of the view laravel will diplay.